# Php curl request returns '405 Not Allowed', Is there any other method for scraping?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, http-status-code-405

I am using php curl, my code is working for other websites but when i request for this url `https://i.local.ch/#q?q=manager&origin=&rid=ac8EV&sort=relevance` it returns:

405 Not Allowed
nginx

Note: SSl is active on my domain

```
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$url="https://i.local.ch/#q?q=manager&origin=&rid=ac8EV&sort=relevance";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r( $info );

echo var_dump($server_output);
```

Comment: Are you sure it should be `POST` and not `GET`, since you're not actually sending any data?

Comment: thanks for replying: 
i have 40 urls for this same website. so do i need to send any data ?

Comment: _"so do i need to send any data"_ - That's impossible for us to answer. We don't know that site. What I meant was that it's not common to access pages using `POST` if you're not passing any data at the same time, like posting a form or similar. So if you just want to get a page, it's normally done through a `GET`-request. And _"405 - Method not allowed"_ indicates that you simply can't access that page using a `POST`-request.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 405 errors are caused when an HTTP method is not allowed by a web server for a requested URL.

Make same request from browser and check request headers. Make sure you are using correct method get, post or put while making request.  Also check if any additional headers are sent with request as some urls only allowed from ajax request and you can achieve this by adding proper headers with request.

You can send additional headers using below method

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Accept-Charset" => "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
    "Keep-Alive" => "115",
    "Connection" => "keep-alive",
    "X-Requested-With" => "XMLHttpRequest"
));
```